# "*" Illegal Character when trying to compile java code

Tags: java, compilation, javac

While trying to compile a small java project, getting an error I never experienced before.
An error occurs whenever I use * to reference either all files or directors.

Running `javac -d .\bin -sourcepath .\ .\*.java .\*\*.java`  leads to an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 2..
```

Full error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 2: .\*.java
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option$37.process(Option.java:693)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Option.handleOption(Option.java:1088)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.doProcessArgs(Arguments.java:381)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.processArgs(Arguments.java:347)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.init(Arguments.java:193)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:229)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:170)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:57)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using Windows. For this error: `Illegal char <*> at index 2: .\*.java` – there are many possible OS versions and terminal/shell tools, but: what happens if you just do `*.java`? (So, remove the leading ".\").

Comment: Sorry to not respond. I observed the same issue you mentioned, error with "\" character. So I wrote a script to run through the subdirectories and compile all .java files as it goes.